# Can gulp / browserSync watch SASS files and update the browser's view on the fly, without explicit save (Ctrl + S)?

Tags: sass, gulp, phpstorm, watch, browser-sync

I've just check out how Phpstorm perform live reloading in the browser when you are editing in debugger mode (HTML / CSS / JS), and I love it because I don't have to press Ctrl + S to see the changes. But to see changes with Gulp SCSS workflow, it is expected that you save the scss file first, in order to see the changes in the browser.

Maybe there is an improvement in the gulp workflow for show changes in the time of writing SCSS, without needing to save? or is posible that in any way???.

This would improve a lot my productivity. I have passed a couple of hours try to find out a solution for this without success.

Thank you.

Comment: no, it's not possible; files have to be changed on disk and not just in memory to get the gulp tasks triggered.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is setting up your Gulp task as a [file watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.1/using-file-watchers.html) in the IDE: with **Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher** enabled, the IDE will save a file as soon as you change it so the transpiler will wake up immediately, and you won't need to press `Ctrl+S` explicitly